# Change AWS RDS secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager, aws-aurora-serverless

I’ve 2 rds serverless clusters for which the secrets are stored in secrets manager. I accidentally attached first cluster's secret to second cluster and vice versa. Now I've some data in the clusters and I want to modify the secrets to point to right cluster. Is there any way of doing it?